# Angular detail component. Display only certain elements of array based on url

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm following the angular tour of heroes tutorial (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6). I want to see if its possible to have the details page loop through an array accessing specific elements based off the page that is routed to

Like the tutorial I have made a details page that is navigated to by clicking a button in a table.

My routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: DefaultComponent,
  children: [{path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'detail/:id', component: DeviceDetailComponent}
  ]
},
```

The button in my dashboard.componenent.html

```
<!-- Button Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef > Actions </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let device" >
      <button mat-button routerLink= "/detail/{{device.id}}">View</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

I have an array with 1d 1-5 and when I click on the button it routes to that url correctly and displays a simple message that works. my detail.componenet.html

```
<p>device{{device.id}} works</p>
```

My plan going forward is to display certain elements from an array depending on the id clicked.

For example I have an array like this:

```
export interface Devices {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  serialNo: number;
}

export const DEVICES: Devices[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Device 1', serialNo: 135421},
  {id: 2, name: 'Device 2', serialNo: 125240},
  {id: 3, name: 'Device 3', serialNo: 124350},
  {id: 4, name: 'Device 4', serialNo: null},
  {id: 5, name: 'Device 5', serialNo: null},
];
```

Would it be possible to only display certain elements like say if you clicked device 1-3 it would route to detail/(1-3) display the Name, and serial number. But if you clicked 4/5 it would just display the name.

My only experience with  looping through an array of objects is like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="let d of DEVICES">
          <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.serialNo }}</td>
```

Is it possible to make it so that d.serialNo only appears on 1-3

Also I feel I should point out, I have been able to do this correctly by making components device1-5 and having a different setup. But I was curious if I could achieve this with just one component. Like the details component in the tutorial

Comment: you can use ngIf and check if the id falls in a certain range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `*ngIf` and checking whether the serialNo starts with 1, 2 or 3

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of DEVICES">
      <td *ngIf="showEntry(d)">{{ d.id }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="showEntry(d)">{{ d.name }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="showEntry(d)">{{ d.serialNo }}</td>
```

**TS**

```
showEntry(device: Devices): boolean {
     return !!(device && 
         (device.serialNo.toString().startsWith('1') ||
          device.serialNo.toString().startsWith('2') ||
          device.serialNo.toString().startsWith('3')
     );
}
```